# How can I check if my servlet is sending compressed content?

Tags: java, servlets, svg, gzip

I'm using a Java servlet with Tomcat to serve SVG files.

When I check gzip on Chrome it seems like it's not working, but if I use [this site](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php)
it says that I have about 90% compression.

The URL I'm using to test my compression is http://losalquimistas.org/wadjet/request?func=getEbook&nombre=prueba&pag=4

How can I be 100% sure that I'm sending compressed content?

Comment: How do you know it's not working in Chrome? (I just tested this in Firefox and it sent gzipped content)

Comment: In Chrome, check the Response Header for "Content-Encoding: gzip" (which it seems to have). In Firefox, the network tab shows the full file size after decompression, but the transfer itself seems to be compressed.

Comment: @immibis I assume it's not working because in the "size/content" column, I always see the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Fiddler. It allows you to sniff http traffic: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: can you elaborate on what should we look on fiddler to know if data is compress or not?